# about beforeCreate in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I don't understand purpose of beforeCreate in Vuejs. If it only perform actions before your component has even been added to the DOM then i only add some line code before use vue instance as follow:

```
 <script>
        var data ={
        c:'',
      };
        var app= new Vue({
          el:"#app",
          data:data,
          beforeCreate:function(){
            data.b="123";
          }

        });
  </script>
```

I don't understand purpose of beforeCreate hook. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i simple want understand purpose of beforeCreate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I simple want understand purpose of beforeCreate

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate) - *"Called synchronously immediately after the instance has been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup."*

Where to use it? I like to use this lifecycle hook to verify if the user is logged or not (JWT in the localestorage/cookie).

Comment: Why you use beforeCreate to verify user? you can use mounted hook,right?

Comment: Because `mounted` is called after the DOM has been mounted or rendered, which takes _some time_ whilst `beforeCreated` doesn't.

Comment: You cannot access localestorage/cookie in befoercreate or created hook. you need mounted to access it

Comment: You can't even access the Vue instance from within `beforeCreate` (try `console.log(this)`) so what use is it?

Comment: @Vucko is there any other use case where we can use `beforeCreate` like we can check if user is logged in `beforeRouteEnter` and redirect to login page?